# convert char* to int* C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this piece of code that I saw it somewhere and I tried to figure out how it works,  but I couldn't.

This is it :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int a = 2;
   char * p = (char *) &a;
   *(p + 1) = 1;
   cout << (int *) p << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I thought that in p it stores the binary of variable a like `00000010`.
Than in the next immediate address it stores `00000001`.
When I try to print `(int *)` p it takes 4 bytes from that address and converts it into int.

When I ran the program the result wasn't that expected. It shows only the address of variable `a`. No change observed.

Could you please explain me how this works and why ?

PS : If I want to show the value of p it shows only 2 not 258 how I expected.

Comment: this `*(p + 1) = 1;` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: why the values of p does not change when converted to int ? Shouldn't it be 258 instead of just 2?

Comment: Why it's not 2^8 + 2^1. That's what I want to know.

Comment: It is only UB if you end up with some sort of garbage/trap representation. Apart from that, you can always split something up in characters/pointer to characters without breaking aliasing rules. It is however implementation-defined behavior, since the code relies both on signedness format and endianess.

Comment: @Lundin: Why trap representation? I also thought you could access any object using char pointer

Comment: @Giorgi You can access every object with a char pointer, that's not the problem. In theory, some systems may implement integers with padding bits, trap representations and other obscure stuff. So if you alter the int through the char pointer and then attempt to do something with the int afterwards, the program might crash on such obscure systems. In practice, almost every single system out there is a two's complement system where every bit combination of an int is valid.

Comment: @Lundin:out of curiosity can you link to standard or some other link?

Comment: It's a system-dependent hack to force bits 8-15 to 00000001. Any particular reason why the owner of the code wanted to do it like that? It's not like `a = (a & ~0xFF00) | 0x0100` is slow?

Comment: @unwind it's `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int)`

Comment: @101010 D'oh. Right. I deleted my comment. Thanks.

Comment: @unwind:did your opinion change about it being ub?

Comment: @Giorgi Yeah, I had the wrong idea that `sizeof (int) > sizeof (char)` is true, but that should be `>=` which makes code accessing the second `char` of an `int` potentially UB.

Comment: @Giorgi The C standard 6.2.6.2.

Comment: @Lundin:hm I read that but it doesn't say exactly what you meant - probably you need to infer it. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule/99010#99010, answer also says you could use char to alias objects. Might be I am missing something

Comment: @Giorgi See my very first comment, aliasing is not the problem, but the signed integer format. Anyway, no point in derailing this question with all these comments, feel free to post a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cout << (int *) p << endl;` would be the same as `cout << &a << endl;` (just the address of `a`).

```
int a = 2;
cout << sizeof(a) << endl;       // 4 (int is 4 bytes)
cout << sizeof(&a) << endl;      // 8 (64b machine, so pointer is 8 bytes)

char *p = (char *) &a;           // p points to first byte of a (normally 4 bytes)
cout << (int) *p << endl;        // 2    // Little Endian, the first byte is actually the last
cout << (int) *(p + 1) << endl;  // 0

*(p + 1) = 1;                    // second byte of a is now set to 1
cout << a << endl;               // a now changes to 258 (0000 0001 0000 0010)
```

Answer (score 2):

> PS : If I want to show the value of p it shows only 2 not 258 how I
>   expected.

The *value* of `p` is the address of the object to which it points. It seems your confusion is here. If you dereference `p` you will get value of object to which it points, that is different.

Hence, in your case `p` is initialized to address of `a`. Afterwards, nothing is assigned to it (e.g. nowhere you do `p=&SomeOtherObject`).

```
   cout << (int *) p << endl; // Print value of pointer -which is address
```

So above you are printing value of `p` which is address of `a`.

As noted keep in mind

```
*(p+1) = 1
```

might be undefined behaviour if `sizeof (int)` is same as `sizeof (char)`